# PayPal doesnt get receiver_email after POST back

Tags: paypal

why i didnt get receiver_email in my check_payment after the user is coming back from his payment on paypal?

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['item_name']);
$sales = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $row['sales']);
$custom_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $custom_url);
$membership = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $row['membership']);
$item_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['item_number']);
$payment_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['payment_status']);
$pending_reason = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['pending_reason']);
$payment_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['mc_gross']);
$payment_currency = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['mc_currency']);
$txn_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['txn_id']);
$receiver_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['receiver_email']);
$payer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['payer_email']);
$payer_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['custom']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, usernameinfo($payer_id,"usern"));
$user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, usernameinfo($payer_id,"email"));
$get = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM purchasify_users ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"));
$admin_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $get['email']);
$pricee = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $row["price_extended"]);

if (!$fp) {
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

so payments working, but i cannot check if the receiver_email was the correct receiver.
I dont have the same paypal mail for every buy, so i must check the seller email in my database with the receiver_email from paypal, but i dont get this here...
But why?

I got everything from the payer like the payer_email, id ,first_name, last_name and more, but not the receiver information

This are the informations that i get

```
Array ( [payer_email] => mail@gmail.com [payer_id] => 123123123 [payer_status] => VERIFIED [first_name] => NAME [last_name] => LASTNAME [address_name] => NAME LASTNAME [address_street] => STREET NR [address_city] => CITY [address_country_code] => DE [address_zip] => ZIPCODE [residence_country] => DE [txn_id] => 123123123123 [mc_currency] => EUR [mc_gross] => 0.01 [protection_eligibility] => INELIGIBLE [payment_gross] => 0.01 [payment_status] => Pending [pending_reason] => unilateral [payment_type] => instant [handling_amount] => 0.00 [shipping] => 0.00 [item_name] => +3 Quotas [item_number] => quotas [quantity] => 1 [txn_type] => web_accept [payment_date] => 2020-03-30T09:32:40Z [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED [custom] => 10 [verify_sign] => 123123-123123-123123 )
```

Comment: Please post a log of the actual POST/body of the IPN message text you received

Comment: @PrestonPHX added to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [payment_status] => Pending
> [pending_reason] => unilateral
> ```

There is no receiver email because that is a unilateral payment, sent to an email that is not associated with a PayPal account

Whoever owns the email it was sent to should create or add it to an existing PayPal account, so they can accept this payment. (Otherwise, it will be automatically refunded in 30 days.)

If this is a common situation, i.e. you have other potential receiving situations that will be unilateral, my recommendation would be to use the INVNUM (invoice number/id) and CUSTOM variables in the original PayPal transaction, which will be returned to you in IPNs. Then your IPN code can match that information to whatever it needs -- including, for example, just sending the receiver email in CUSTOM if that is all you need.

Comment: Oh thanks!

Yeah i typed in an email that not exists for testing and test with 0.01€ without sandbox, thats the reason i think :D

I will test it soon with a real mail

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!